# Using spring extensions language EL with systemProperties

Tags: spring, el

I have set following environment variables:

```
export yardstick-spark.aws.key=xxx
export yardstick-spark.aws.secret-key=yyy
```

And in the application-context.xml:

```
<bean id="aws.creds" class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
  <constructor-arg value="#{systemProperties['yardstick-spark.aws.key']}" />
  <constructor-arg value="#{systemProperties['yardstick-spark.aws.secret-key']}" />
```

However the environment variables  are not available:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Access key cannot be null.
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:270)
    ... 45 more
```

Is there an additional step required - e.g. to set up an EL resolver ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't system properties, they're environment properties. Use

```
<constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['yardstick-spark.aws.key']}" />
```

Comment: ah yah.. I changed mid-flight from system to env - but my mind only made half of the journey.